# setActivationPolicy to Regular and openWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

On `applicationDidFinishLaunching` application `activationPolicy` is set to `Prohibited` (to hide the dock icon).

I have a method that sets it to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular` (to be able to open and focus the window) then opens the window, but I have to run it twice to work. The set policy doesn't affect the `openWindow:` method.

```
- (void)openWindow {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    [NSApp openWindow:window];
}
```

Do I need to delay the `openWindow:`?

Answer (score 0):

When do you call `openWindow`? Maybe you should place the calling after the `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

By the way, if you want to hide the dock icon and be able to focus on the window, you should try `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` other than `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited`.